How do i restore Ubuntu Gnome Desktop settings
I uninstalled (completely) emacs to prepare for re-installation.  It seemed that the emacs package contains system apps of some sort... because when I went to make "ubuntu desktop" changes, I got the error message that is attached.  I have not filed a launchpad issue as it was way over my head.
The Ubuntu Desktop (from settings) worked previously.  What magic do I need to do to restore it.  One consequence is that my dash does not automatically pop up and I had the dash on both of my dual monitor setup and it disappeared on my secondary monitor.


You obviously uninstalled a lot more than emacs. You can look in /var/log/apt/history.log to see what you uninstalled. Next time, look at what it tells you it is going to uninstall before agreeing to it.

A removal of emacs would remove very little, ie. look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/emacs and you see only emacs packages are related.... You gave no specifics as to what you actually removed; was it the official package from my link? or something else, as we're limited to the details you provide.

@Organic Marble, yes, I should have taken a break... I was very lazy verifying what was to be removed.  Thanks for pointer to log.  I don't remember what all (if I chose more -- besides "complete removal") I selected.  I'm hopeful that when I upgrade to 24.04 the issue will resolve itself.
